# Change URL path when using FTP

Tags: url, ftp

I'm trying to upload a file to a sever for a repository I am making.  When I use FTP to upload the UDID.php the .php will map itself to the exact URL as it's name **(ex using hi.txt http://my.site.org/hi.txt)**  I would like the UDID.php file to be mapped to another URL when I upload it **(ex actual file is hi.txt and i want it to be mapped to http://my.site.org/example)**  Is there any way to do this?  I am using iPage as my host if that helps

Answer (score 2):

FTP is  purely a protocol for transferring files, so there's no way to "map" the request to a different file on the server. You could copy the file and give it a different name on the server, but I don't think that's what you're asking.

To achieve what you're setting out to do you would need to modify the web server configuration rather than the FTP connection, but I'm not sure it's a great idea :).

Copying fileA and naming it something different is trivial with FTP (once you've connected):

```
ftp> put project/hi.txt www/example
```

In the example above `project/hi.txt` is the path to the file on your local machine, and `www/example` is the path and filename it will be copied to on the server.

A lot of web hosts will have a `public` or `www` directory to put files to be served into.

Comment: So this is an ftp command?  Also what do project and www mean in this case?

Comment: Yeah if you're using FTP from the command line you could issue a command like that once you've connected. I've updated the answer to explain what the files mean :)

Comment: Sadly, the file does not keep it's mime type and run the script.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The mime type is set by the web server, it's not an attribute of the file. If you're transferring plain text a web server will *usually* default to `text/plain` for unknown content types. Could you explain what you're trying to achieve a bit more?